# beeswarm plot in SHAP: why do some features have more instances than others?

Tags: python, shap

Take this plot, for instance:

[image]

Why so many dots for `daily_time_spent_onsite` but only a few dots for `male`?

If every dot is the feature's SHAP value for one specific sample, shouldn't every feature show the same number of dots?

I couldn't find any explanation in the [docs](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/beeswarm.html).

Answer (score 1):

See this guide to interpreting [SHAP plots](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-machine-learning-with-xgboost-9ec80d148d27).

Dots that don’t fit on the row pile up to show density. Every row (feature) should contain a dot for every occurence.